# Mysql Subquery Result

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have to just select the values from outer query based on the result set of inner query.

```
Table 1:
row 1 : abc   
row 2: def
```

Table 2:
row 1: column name `doc_id values =  1,2` (comma separated values)

```
select * from table 1 where id IN (select doc_id from table 2)
```

but it shows me only one row, it has to show two rows.

Comment: Please fix your formatting.  And you should avoid using CSV in your table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INNER JOIN ON vs WHERE clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause)

Comment: table 2 has one record with csv like 1,2,3 , how to pass it in subquery if I pass it in subquery the subquery return this as a staring not searching for each

Comment: do you mean table2 has 1 row with two (or possibly more) comma separated values you need to explode into 2 (or possibly more) rows?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like [`find_in_set`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   table2
               WHERE  FIND_IN_SET (table1.id, table2.doc_id) > 0)
```

Comment: It works but for all rows it gives same result what happen if we have 2 records in the table 2